# How process JSON data that needs to be unpivoted?

Tags: c#, json, ssis, sql-server-2012, unpivot

I have a JSON source that has a weird layout where there are unknown amount of columns.

https://theunitedstates.io/congress-legislators/committee-membership-current.json

The format is like the following:

```
ColumnHeaders =>    HLAG     HSAG    HSAG01 .... to unknown
Single row of Data  JSON     JSON    JSON
```

How can I get the data like this:

```
Col1     Col2
HLAG     JSON
HSAG     JSON
HSAG01   JSON
```

I am currently working in SSIS so I have C# solutions available to me.

I just don't know how to deal with unknown columns in SSIS.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to modify your source connection to use a query to pivot the data as it comes in?

Comment: what version of sql server are you on?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 1):

In case you cannot find a more convenient solution, here's how it could be done using the command-line tool, [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
jq -jrc 'keys_unsorted[] as $key | $key,"\t",.[$key],"\n" ' committee-membership-current.json
```

This produces one line per "column-header" in accordance with the problem description, using a literal tab ("\t") as separator.  A different separator can be specified in the obvious manner.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It would take extra effort to just understand what your answer does?

Answer (score 1):

There are many articles online describing the process of parsing complex Json, the main idea is to use a script component with `System.Web.Extensions` assembly. I think that the following article is what you are looking for:

- [Importing Complex JSON files using SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5352/importing-complex-json-files-using-sql-server-integration-services/)

Other helpful articles:

- [Approaches to Import JSON in SSIS (SQL Server 2016+) Part 1](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/approaches-to-import-json-in-ssis-sql-server-2016-part-1-1)
- [Importing JSON Files Using SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5307/importing-json-files-using-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: I am well beyond the criteria in the following links which demonstrate creating a class(es) for deserializing into. My problem is the JSON returned a data set with unlimited columns all with  one row of data. I needed to unpivot this into rows before I could process and was lucky and found that the tool my company purchased allowed just this as a property of the GUI.