# Reading JSON file into a table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am trying to read JSON files from a location and write to SQL server table. The files in the location change everyday, as a result I may need to find a dynamic way to select file name.

I have tried to use the `OPENROWSET`, however I read that I cannot parametize the location name with that. I tried to use `OPENROWSET` with a dynamic query but I get an error that file location can not be found. After reading about it seems it could be a folder permission issue.

What I am not trying and hoping to get help with is how I can read the JSON text file and write the data into a table and then I can use the `OPENJSON` function from there.

Can anyone help me with how I can load a SQL server with the JSON data in some sort of a blob using T-SQL or SSIS.

Comment: Check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534451/how-process-json-data-that-needs-to-be-unpivoted/56550274#56550274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Bulk Import data from file

```
Select BulkColumn from openrowset(Bulk'D:\home\HS\HS-Web\wwwroot\Json files\test.json',single_blob)JSON;
```

--View the imported data from Bulk Import as a single column

```
DECLARE @TestDetails VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @TestDetails = BulkColumn FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK'D:\Omkar\Projects\HS\Documents\test.json', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON;

SELECT @TestDetails as SingleRow_Column
```

--Check if imported data is valid data or not if=1 data is valid

```
if(ISJSON(@TestDetails)=1)
BEGIN
PRINT 'Valid Data Imported'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'Invalid Data Imported'
END
GO
```

--Now Select Data to be added to table here $.tests is array object name

```
SELECT testCode,Test,Method FROM OPENJSON(@TestDetails, '$.Tests')
WITH(
testCode nvarchar(50)'$.testCode',
Test nvarchar(50)'$.Test',
Method nvarchar(50)'$.Method'
)
```

--Now insert data into table if default values need to be inserted then in select take default value

```
Insert into TestDetails(Active,CreatedDate,testCode,Test,Method)
SELECT '1','2019-10-23 06:01:10.7927233',testCode,Test,Method FROM 
OPENJSON(@TestDetails, '$.Tests')
WITH(
testCode nvarchar(50)'$.testCode',
Test nvarchar(50)'$.Test',
Method nvarchar(50)'$.Method'
)[Json file Screen Shot][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I get this correctly, your issue is not about how to read the JSON, but rather how to get the file?

As you found out, any interaction with the file system out of SQL-Server (`T-SQL`) can get very tricky. SQL-Server is restricted to its own user and will see its own machine. So a path on `C:\` might not be the one you expected.

However, before fiddling around with permissions, kerberos for *acting as*-authentication and shared paths I'd suggest to create a staging table like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.JSONImport_staging
                           (ID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_JSONImport_staging PRIMARY KEY
                           ,ImportDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_JSONImport_staging_ImportDate DEFAULT(SYSUTCDATETIME())
                           ,FileLocation NVARCHAR(1000) NULL
                           ,Content NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
                           ,ProcessedOn DATETIME2 NULL
                           ,Success BIT NULL);
```

And use one of the many approaches you'll find on the net to store data in such a table

- PowerShell (something [along this](https://www.sqlshack.com/6-methods-write-powershell-output-sql-server-table/))
- Any programming language of your choice
- SSIS
- and many more

You can easily use an external sheduled job to check for files and shift them into the staging table and then use an internal job (within SQL-Server) to check for unprocessed files and read them into the target tables.

As always in such cases:

- Keep the staging table as open, generic and error tolerant as possible.
- Do any integrity check, conversion and processing transaction-safe on the way between your staging table and the target tables.

Comment: Correct. Have been checking on the net on how to store data into the table thats where I have been struggling. I am restricted to using SSIS and TSQL. I like the idea of the staging table. I used that combined with SSIS Import Column, but my content column, (using your column names) broght out some HEX characters. Not what i expected.

Comment: @BRILLIANT If the `Content` is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` you can read a string file into this directly. Make sure, that you handle encodings (utf-8, utf-16, and many more) correctly. If you see HEX codes (and you defined `Content` as `VARBINARY(MAX)`), you can try to cast this to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. But this is dangerous. SQL-Server is very restricted with encodings... Starting with v2014 SP2 there is utf-8 import with `BULK`...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a file can be access by SQL

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JsonFile') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #JsonFile;

CREATE TABLE #JsonFile
    (
        [JsonLine] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

BULK INSERT #JsonFile
FROM '\\UNC_path\file.json'
WITH ( ROWTERMINATOR = '' );

SELECT *
FROM   #JsonFile;
```

Comment: You really should read JSON into `NVARCHAR(MAX)`... Besides the fact, that acessing files from within `T-SQL` using `BULK` can get really ugly, you will have to use [some more parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like `CODEPAGE` to get a correct result...